# Dreamweaver PhoneGap Form or User Login Page

Tags: php, dreamweaver, phonegap-build

I would like to build an iOS app using Dreamweaver and PhoneGap. I am familiar with Dreamweaver. However, when it comes to talking to a database PhoneGap doesn't allow PHP, which is how you'd otherwise connect to a server side database in Dreamweaver.

I'd like to see an example of a simple user login or similar form that can communicate with a database without PHP.

Examples? Hints? Thank you so much for taking a look at my question.

Comment: Node.js ? or deployd maybe for local server ?

Comment: I think you are correct in suggesting node.js atleast I can use js on the server. I don't think there is an easy answer to this problem. I have found a couple examples of work arounds as not including php is a problem with all Phonegap programs that need to work with a database. However, none of them, that I have found, deal with or plug-into dreamweaver. Come on Adobe... Seriously... It seems like they expect me to build a front end for an app and then just hand all the backend off to database developer. Whereas, If I build a regular website I can do it all right within Deamweaver.

Comment: Here is a link to a tutorial that I found informational if not completely helpful.

http://www.indiageeks.in/phonegap-jquery-ajax-example-jsonjavascript-object-notation-response/